# What is wrong with my DLLImport of LogonUser with String Marshaling? [C#]

Tags: c#, marshalling, dllimport

For some odd reason, when I marshal the `LogonUser DLLImport` parameters I am no longer able to login succesfully when using the `INTERACTIVE` logon type, it works for `NETWORK` logon type.

This is my code:

```
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool LogonUser
        (
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        String lpszUsername,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        String lpszDomain,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        String lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType,
        int dwLogonProvider,
        out IntPtr hToken
        );

    bResult = LogonUser(
        "username",
        ".",
        "password",
        (int)LogonType.INTERACTIVE,     // = 2
        (int)LogonProvider.DEFAULT,     // = 0
        out hToken
        );
```

Now, as-is my call to LogonUser fails (`Logon Exception: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password`), but if I remove the `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]`s from the `DLLImport` it works fine, also if I switch to `LogonType.NETWORK` it works fine, why is it different with `INTERACTIVE`?

Sadly I need to keep it as I use this with other functions such as `LoadUserProfile` that needs it to be Marshalled (only way I could get it to work and not display unknown windows characters [squares]). Do I need to do some funky marshaling of strings or something to get it to validate correctly?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LogonUser takes an LP**T**STR, not an LPSTR, as parameters.  You should just use the default string marshaling, and it will work correctly.

See [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [pinvoke.net's declaration for a property P/Invoke of LogonUser](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.logonuser).

Comment: Odd thing is - when I call LoadUserProfile(...) with the token obtained from LogonUser, is it is not done with Marshalling the profile name create has unrecognized characters (those squares) when viewed from explorer - but works fine if I marshal them as shown.

Odd no?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but the cause was different. Then I realized that in the place I work we must log-on our machines with a digital certificate instead of user and password.

I had forgotten that we have this restriction on our domain.

So I have to use another domain account, instead of mine, to test my application.

I don't know if these information will help but, but they maybe be of some use for other people.